# Pass by value or reference with recursion implementing Heap Sort

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am attempting to implement heap sort using the psuedo code from the book [Intro to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844). The following is what I have:

```
def parent(i):
    return i/2

def left(i):
    return 2*i

def right(i):
    return 2*i+1

def max_heapify(seq, i, n):
    l = left(i)
    r = right(i)

    if l <= n and seq[n] > seq[i]:
        largest = l
    else:
        largest = i
    if r <= n and seq[r] > seq[largest]:
        largest = r

    if largest != i:
        seq[i], seq[largest] = seq[largest], seq[i]
        max_heapify(seq, largest, n)

def heap_length(seq):
    return len(seq) - 1

def build_heap(seq):
    n = heap_length(seq)
    for i in range(n/2,0,-1):
        max_heapify(seq, i, n)

def sort(seq):
    build_heap(seq)
    heap_size = heap_length(seq)
    for i in range(heap_size,1,-1):
        seq[1], seq[i] = seq[i], seq[1]
        heap_size = heap_size - 1
        max_heapify(seq, 1, heap_size)

    return seq
```

I am having issues with understanding passing by value or by reference in Python. I have looked at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) and it seems that I am passing the list by value. My questions is how to return the correctly sorted list either by reference or by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrays are always passed by reference
if you want to pass by value use slice

`my_func(my_array[:])` #send copy

`my_func(my_array) #array is modified inside and changes are reflected in original`

Comment: Hmm then I wonder if my code is incorrect? When I return the list it doesn't seem to modify the list.

Comment: x = some_func(ar);  would  apply any modifications to ar and return a different (or same) array as x

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing that in my `__main__` but I get the unsorted list that I had before.